# Handling User Sign up and Sign in using RxSwift in MVVM pattern

Tags: swift, rx-swift

I am building an iOS App using RxSwift based on a MVVM pattern. I have a basic signUp/logIn form upon app start and was wondering how to handle those cases correctly in terms of clean reactive programming: Basically I am using the [RxSwift GitHub example](https://github.com/ReactiveX/RxSwift/tree/master/RxExample/RxExample/Examples/GitHubSignup/UsingDriver) as a blueprint for my login form, but this only handles the "login", not the "signUp". The concrete issue being the fact, that I have a `let loggedIn: Driver<Bool>` in my LoginViewModel, on which my LoginViewController will be subscribed, in order to perform appropriate actions upon login, but `loggedIn` does not only need to be triggered when pressing the "login button", but the LoginViewModel should also login, after the "signUp button" was being pressed.

Assuming we are instantiating the LoginViewModel from the LoginViewController using the following init:

```
init(
    username: Driver<String>,
    password: Driver<String>,
    signUpTaps: Signal<Void>,
    signInTaps: Signal<Void>
    ) {
```

we use the following code (in the LoginViewModel) to login the user upon a "signIn" tap event being sent from the LoginViewController:

```
let usernameAndPassword = Driver.combineLatest(input.username, input.password) { (username: $0, password: $1) }

loggedIn = signInTaps.withLatestFrom(usernameAndPassword)
        .flatMapLatest { usernameAndPassword in
            return API.loginUser(with: usernameAndPassword.username, and: usernameAndPassword.password)
            .asDriver(onErrorJustReturn: false)
    }
```

where API is just my class with static methods, being responsible for creating network requests (as signing up- and logging in users). Note that inside my LoginViewModel no subscriptions are being made!

How do I distinguish between "signUp" and "´signIn" button pressed in this reactive manner, in order to set the observable `loggedIn` correctly for both cases?
In order to trigger a "login" request just after successful "signUp", I could just use `flatMap()`, but then how do I only login?
I also thought about something like

```
loggedIn = Observable.combineLatest(signInTaps.withLatestFrom(usernameAndPassword), signUpTaps.withLatestFrom(usernameAndPassword))
```

and then somehow differentiate between both events, in order to determine, if I have to signUp a user first and then signIn, or just need to signIn the user.

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Well, imo, you shouldn't use `logIn` after `signUp`. What I suggest, is make the API respond with an user model after finishing the request successfully for both cases. This way, you can `merge` both streams, and use the same handler. But, in case you can't change the API, `flatMap` would be the solution, just like you said. You just need to have two different streams which binds to the same handler. One will `flatMap` directly to the `logIn`, and other will use `signUp` and then `logIn`. I hope I could be clear enough, and could help you somehow :)